# Weird Firefox overflow/float behavior

Tags: html, css

I have a [simple layout](http://195.228.155.116/szilk/public/templates/globallog/bemutatkozas.html) which works fine in Chrome, Safari even Opera too (OS X). The surprise for me here is Firefox. (IE and Win not tested yet).

The problem is `fieldset.ownerbox` isn't floating in Firefox. (The two semi-transparent fieldset below the pie-chart)

CSS rules applied here:

```
#owners {
position: relative;
width: 940px;
left: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
z-index: 1;
top: -240px;
font-size: 16px;
}
.ownerbox {
width: 310px;
height: 150px;
padding: 10px;
margin-right: 20px;
float: left;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
color: #000;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
}
.ownerbox.large {
width: 500px;
padding: 0px 10px 20px 10px;
}
```

Please help, what's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readjust your widths so it takes padding into account. You can `overflow-x:hidden;` on `#owners` to see how it looks "contained".

Alternatively adjust the width on #owners.

**Edit: Seems you just need to `clear:both` on `#owners`.**

Comment: When i set overflow: auto; on #owners Firefox renders layout correctly except that the pie-chart clips on top and bottom.

Comment: The floated list above #owners made this?? Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't be using `top:-240px` and `position:relative` as you are. I think you need to adjust your layout to not rely so much on relative positioning. If you have lots of cases like that, it's a bad sign and usually means go back, kill the position relatives and find another way of layout.

Comment: Did you mean it's unnecessary to use pos: relative in this layout? Can i achieve the same with floats? Normally i'm using floats mostly but this time i tried this out. Looks like i've overlooked relative positioning a little bit :o

Comment: thx so much it solved my own problem (that's what stackoverflow is meant to do) but I can't understand why the clear:both resolv the problem...